# Adding pagination to Ajax Query

Tags: ajax, pagination

I have a search page.  It works like this.

- **(1)** User searches using form in the homepage
- **(2)** User is taken to search results page
- **(3)** If user modifies the search term( there is form with in the search results) then the results are loaded using ajax and i am running a query in it.

---

Is it possible to have a pagination for ajax in 3rd step?

If i am using the `paginate_links()`in the results of step (2)..it shows pagination,  but in 3rd step when ajax request is made the pagination doesn't shows.

Did i coded wrong or it is like that?

Comment: can you explain bit more your code? can you show your ajax call to fetch contents?

Comment: @AndréKelling it's having a lot of code , let me try if i can simplyfy